# Сбивается таймер обратного отсчета при Slick slider

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

У меня есть слайдер с 5 элементами, у которых есть таймер обратного отсчёта, при перезагрузки сайта время показывается нормально, но при скролле слайдера время сбивается

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Ошибка там